# In JavaScript, when creating an element, and then deleting the containing variable, does the element stay in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I have a script that asynchronously loads image `src` from XML file.
The sources are later assigned to the `background` of a `div`, and `background`s change every 5 seconds.
It works well, but I want to pre-load the actual images to display already loaded image.
I do this by iterating an array, creating an `img` for each source:

```
for(var i=0; i < clientLogos.lenght; i++){
    var imgHolder = document.createElements("IMG");
    imgHolder.src = clientLogos[i];
}
```

It's hard to tell the difference if it has been preloaded in development stage, so my question is:
If I delete or over-write the variable containing the element I just created, does the element stay in DOM, or does it get deleted as well?

I'm pretty sure it stays, but I want to ask the more experienced developers.

I got confused with it:
Does `document.createElement()` inserts it in the DOM or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The newly created element will stay in the DOM unless you explicitly remove it or you overwrite the `.innerHTML` property of some parent node.

when deleting ("nulling") `imgHolder` you are only deleting a reference to that node.

Comment: What if the created element wasn't inserted into any other element? Where would it reside in the DOM?

Comment: @Dean: Then it would never have been part of the document, and hence, never been in the DOM. (Technically speaking, it would have been an independent document all by itself that got deleted once it was no longer reachable.)

Comment: @Dean: well, if you never call `appendChild()` for instance to insert (append) that created node somewhere and you overwrite it, it's gone. Think of it like a template which is used to create a new DOM node. After it was successfuly inserted into the DOM, you can access that node with the reference hold in `imgHolder`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant created inside document, like: document.createElement("TAG"). Where can it be seen in the DOM?

Comment: @Dean: nowhere. You need to call a method like `.appendChild`, `.insertBefore` etc. etc. to bring that "memory"ish object into the DOM.

Comment: @jAndy: from what you wrote above, all the images I created in the loop are thrown away. I'm confused.

Comment: @Dean: yes they are thrown away. After your loop has finished `imgHolder` will contain the last image node that was created. But it is still not in the DOM.

Comment: @jAndy: I read all the answers and comments on the page, I think I got it. The ceated `element` resides in the variable, which is stored in memory, if variable is deleted - the created `element` is gone. Also despite `createElement()` being a method of `document`, it is not stored in the document (or DOM), unless `appendChild()` is called. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

it will be lost. the only way to access it is by assigning the same to some new variable and delete the DOM variable that holds it value.

Answer (score 1):

In your given example element will be freed when its **reference** count will drop to 0. Have to perform `appendChild` or such before writing to that variable to prevent it.

```
var imgHolder;
imgHolder = document.createElement("IMG");  // creates and references new Image
imgHolder.src = 'hello.jpg';                // some manip
/* have to save object here by means of inserting into DOM or merely pushing into array */
/* failure to do so tells JS's garbage collector what old object no longer needed */
imgHolder = document.createElement("IMG");  // deletes old image referenced by variable, creates and refs new one
```

Comment: @user205376: and what about the loop? `imgHolder` is an Array in my example.

Comment: Hmm, in your example imgHolder is object (HTMLElement, to be exact), and you are overwriting it on the each iteration. Perform someArray.push(imgHolder) to preserve

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I got confused between scripts, I have another one very similar to this. Thanks